# How to make swagger working with jersey2 and JAX-RS on tomcat 7

Tags: spring, tomcat7, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, swagger

I am trying to use swagger in order to document my Rest APIs. I use following link to setup with jersey2 and JAX-RS on tomcat

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5

But I could not access either `/swagger.json` or `/api-docs`. Its responding with 404.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a workable documentation? Please help....

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try to better boil down, which part of the documentation is not yet working in your case.

For me, I used Jersey 2.5.1, and swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10 v. 1.3.4.

I went with the solution to initialize Swagger by a bootstrap class which I included in my web.xml.

**bootstrap class**

```
public class SwaggerBootstrap extends HttpServlet {

@Override public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) {
    try {

    ServletContext sc = servletConfig.getServletContext();

    //as of servlet api 2.5
    String ctxPath = sc.getContextPath();               
    String apiversion = "your-api-version";
    String hostname = "your-hostname";

    ConfigFactory.config().setBasePath("http://"+hostname+":8080"+ctxPath);
    ConfigFactory.config().setApiPath("http://"+hostname+":8080"+ctxPath);      
    ConfigFactory.config().setApiVersion(apiversion);       
    ConfigFactory.config().setSwaggerVersion(com.wordnik.swagger.core.SwaggerSpec.version());


    System.out.println("Swagger:");
    System.out.println("api hostname:"+hostname);
    System.out.println("context path:"+ctxPath);
    System.out.println("api-version:"+apiversion);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Failed to configure swagger");
}
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing</param-value>
    </init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SwaggerBootstrap</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.package.swagger.SwaggerBootstrap</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: you are using com.wordnik.swagger package, but I am using io.swagger package, which doesn't contain lots of sub package(s) and classes such as JaxrsApiReader, Documentation, Endpoint etc. Should I start to use com.wordnik.swagger??!

Comment: Probably this is not necessary, if you want to go with the latest 1.5 version, which would be good idea in my opinion. As they say, they just repackaged it. Maybe try to go with the initialization in [web.xml](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#using-swaggers-servlet-in-the-webxml) first, what I have done in the bootstrap class. This seems to be more straightful.

Comment: If that doesn't work you can still downgrade, if you feel, there is more usage and documentation in the previous version.